# C# Limit creation of class instance to within namespace

Tags: c#, class-design, access-modifiers

I have two objects, `RoomManager` and `Room`, there will be several `Room`s and one `RoomManager`.  I want the `RoomManager` to be the only one allowed to create a `Room` object. So I'm wondering if there is a way to make the `Room` constructor (and the rest of the `Room` methods/properties) only accessible to the `RoomManager`. I was thinking maybe moving them to their own namespace and making `Room` private or internal or something. From [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I see that internal is for the entire assembly though, not just the namespace.

Comment: Whenever I see XManager I remember this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager.html

Comment: You could make `Room` a private class inside `RoomManager`?

Comment: @Nicholas, nice article.. must read. :D

Comment: @Nicholas, good article, I hadn't read that one. I also like the first comment "Well I feel smart. I just renamed every *Manager class to *Helper."  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, C# (and .NET in general) has no access modifiers which are specific to namespaces.

One fairly hack solution would be to make Room just have a private constructor, and make RoomManager a nested class (possibly just called Manager):

```
public class Room
{
    private Room() {}

    public class Manager
    {
        public Room CreateRoom()
        {
            return new Room(); // And do other stuff, presumably
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Room.Manager manager = new Room.Manager();
Room room = manager.CreateRoom();
```

As I say, that's a bit hacky though. You *could* put Room and RoomManager in their own assembly, of course.

Comment: Room and RoomManager will only ever be needed for one program, so putting them in their own assembly seems like overkill. Is your "Manager class inside Room class" approach too hacky to actually be used?

Comment: @jon: i would say its not hacky at all, it is a great way how to make these kind of controllers, managers ect ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
var room = Room.Factory.Create();
```

If the constructor of Room is private, it will still be accessible from Room.Factory if you declare the factory class inside the Room class.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the Room inside of RoomManager itself and making it's constructor private could be helpful.

**EDIT :**
  But the best solution I think is that to extract an abstract class of the Room, and expose that class to clients.

No one can create an instance of the abstract class.

Comment: In this case the constructor won't be accessible from RoomManager.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following with the "extract an abstract class of the Room" part. I do need to create instances of the Room class. Could you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement '[Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)'. It creates object only once and any subsequent attemps to create object of that type will actually returns already created object.
You should create class factory which would implement singleton for `RoomManager`. `Room`, in turn, should be private type of `RoomNamager`. `RoomNamager` manager should have method for `Room` creation. But in this case you cannot access `Room` properties outside of `RoomManager` class. To solve this problem I recomend you to create `IRoom` public interface which would grant access to room functionality. So your `create room` method would return `IRoom` interface.