# Protected Internal Member

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between ‘protected’ and ‘protected internal’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal)

I have seen a lot of controversy over the true meaning of declaring a member protected internal.

Under this context is the member's access modifier either "protected or internal" or "protected and internal"?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) is clear that it is "protected or internal".

That is - a member is accessible both within the assembly and any subtype.

> **protected internal**
>   The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

Comment: "The documentation is clear"...but i saw that ninja edit where you switched "and" to "or".  :)

Comment: ...if you inherit from the class, into a different assembly, you will not have access to the member, even though it is protected.

Comment: @cHao - Aye. [Dangers of copy-paste](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2490884/1583) :(