# Inconsistent accessibility: proper type 'Database' is less accessible than property 'BaseClass.dtBase'

Tags: c#

Please can someone help with the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: proper type 'Database' is less accessible
>   than property 'BaseClass.dtBase'

I cannot run my program due to error message of inconsistent.

> My error is dtBase on Protected Database {get; set;}, always red line.

Here's my delivery class.

```
namespace Payroll_System
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        protected Database dtBase { get; set; }

        public BaseClass()
        {
            dtBase = new Database();
        }

        public string DBText(string Value)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}", Value).Replace("'", "''");
        }
    }

    public class Employee: BaseClass 
    {
        public Employee()
        {

        }

        public string IDNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string PhilHealthNo { get; set; }
        public string PhilHealth { get; set; }
        public string SSSNo { get; set; }
        public string SSS { get; set; }
        public string eDate { get; set; }

        public void Insert()
        {
            dtBase.CommandText("INSERT into Employee(eIDNo, eName, eAddress, eContactNo, eDesignation, eGender, ePhilHealthNo, ePhilHealth, eSSSNo, eSSS, edate) values(@IDNo, @Name, @Address, @ContactNo, @Designation, @Gender, @PhilHealthNo, @PhilHealth, @SSSNo, @SSS");
            dtBase.AddParameter("@IDNo", this.IDNo);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@Name", this.Name);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@Address", this.Address);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@ContactNo", this.ContactNo);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@Designation", this.ContactNo);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@Gender", this.Gender);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@PhilHealthNo", this.PhilHealthNo);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@PhilHealth", this.PhilHealth);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@SSSNo", this.SSSNo);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@SSS", this.SSS);
            dtBase.AddParameter("@Date", this.eDate.ToString());
            dtBase.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your class `Database`? What if you append `public class ` before the class definition?

Comment: namespace Payroll_System
{
    class Database
    {
        public static SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand comm;

        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        public Database() :
           this ("dbPayrollSystem")
        {

        }

        public Database(string config)
        {
            ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[config].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `Database` is declared as internal. (If it is not declared `public` then it defaults to `internal`)

This code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
     protected Database DtBase { get; set; }
}
```

implies that code external to this library can create a new class that inherits from `BaseClass`, and this new class should be able to access an item of type `Database` via the `DtBase` member. But this is an error, because `Database` is not public and is not accessible outside the library.

One choice is to declare `Database` as `public`

```
public class Database
{
}

public class BaseClass
{
     protected internal Database DtBase(...) {}
}
```

---

It would be great if C# had a way of setting the accessibility to `protected AND internal`. But, it turns out you cannot do that. (`protected internal` does not mean what you might automatically think it means, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal))

Comment: Because it is wrong. Making the base class `protected internal` doesn't help fixing the issue.

Comment: `protected internal` is "OR", not "AND". There has been some discussion about adding the "AND" variant but it's not yet present in C#.

Comment: Language proposal for [`private protected`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/private-protected.md)

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, Thank you. My Database is not in public. Class Databse only. I can run my program now.