# How corefx works with HttpMessageHandler?

Tags: .net-core

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageHandler.cs#L20

```
protected internal abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs#L51

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = _handler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

How to call protected method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `protected`. It's `protected internal`. Which means "`protected` OR `internal`". This method can be called by any code in the same assembly.

[What is the difference between 'protected' and 'protected internal'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal)